# XAMPP won't open PHP files in directory (Mac)

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

All the servers are running correctly in XAMPP, and I when I run http://localhost the XAMPP page comes up. However when I try to run a php through xampp by accessing the directory where the file is stored, i.e.,

```
http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gallery.php
```

I get error 404. I've tried loads of different paths, but here is the path to the file in finder [*path image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hHFk.png)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It should just be `http://localhost/gallery.php`

Comment: Over http, "localhost" serves "DOCUMENT ROOT".. eg; the top directory Apache can serve pages from, htdocs in this case, so yes, Jay is correct http://localhost/gallery.php should work

Comment: Oh right. That works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your webserver is resolving the domain `localhost` to a specific directory, the so called `document root`. (this can be adjusted in your server config). I would assume that it points to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs`. so your file should be accessible via

> http://localhost/gallery.php